# Ruby - Print only the values of dubplicate hash keys in an array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, xml, parsing, hash

I have created an array of hashes from data ive to pull in from an xml file. Problem is, some of the hash keys in the array are duplicates and id like to pull just the values.  For example, the code below outputs the following:

```
{"server_host"=>"hostone", "server_type"=>"redhat", "server_name"=>"RedhatOne"}
{"server_host"=>"hostone", "server_type"=>"windows", "server_name"=>"WinOne"}
```

and i'd like to be able print out this:

```
{"server_host"=>"hostone", "server_type"=>"redhat", "server_name"=>"RedhatOne"}
                           "server_type"=>"windows", "server_name"=>"WinOne"}
```

I think i need to create another array based on duplicate keys but what i am trying below is not working:

```
   def parse_xml_file(filename)
      require 'nokogiri'
      xmlSource = File.read(filename)
      parsedXml = Nokogiri::XML(xmlSource)

      hostArray = Array.new
      parsedXml.xpath("/New/Server").each do |srvNode|
      hostNode = srvNode.at_xpath("Host")
      hostArray << {"server_name"=>srvNode["Name"], 
      "server_type"=>srvNode["Type"], "server_host"=>hostNode["Address"] } 

      grouped = hostArray.group_by{|row| [row[:server_host]]}
      filtered = grouped.values.select { |a| a.size > 1 }.flatten

   end
```

Comment: understood what you are doing in your code, but can you elaborate more on what exactly you want to print here? That output you are expecting looks erroneous

Comment: Yes. This is unclear. As I understand you want : `{ server_host: "...", types: [ {...}, {...} ]`. Correct ?

Comment: I want to be able to pick out everything related to 'hostone' for example, to be able to retrieve the fact that there is a redhat and windows server with the name 'hostone' - if that makes sense?
i appreciate you taking the time to try and help btw.

Comment: yes - Valentin Trinque -  that would be correct -- apologies for poor description!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a variable `hash_arr` which contains your duplicated hashes, here is some code that should get you pretty close to where you want to be. It's not optimized, but it's simple enough to understand:

```
hash_arr.group_by { |h| h["server_host"] }.each do |host_name, values|
  puts "Server Host: #{host_name}"
  values.each do |val|
    val.delete("server_host")
    puts val
  end
end
```

prints out:

```
Server Host: hostone
{"server_type"=>"redhat", "server_name"=>"RedhatOne"}
{"server_type"=>"windows", "server_name"=>"WinOne"}
```

Or if you just the values per group without associating them across hashes:

```
hash_arr =[{"server_host"=>"hostone", "server_type"=>"redhat", "server_name"=>"RedhatOne"}, {"server_host"=>"hostone", "server_type"=>"windows", "server_name"=>"WinOne"}]

merged_hash = {}

hash_arr.each do |hash|
    hash.each do |k, v|
        merged_hash[k] ||= []
        merged_hash[k] << v
    end
end

merged_hash.values.each(&:uniq!)
```

And then the output:

```
[9] pry(main)> merged_hash
=> {"server_host"=>["hostone"], "server_type"=>["redhat", "windows"], "server_name"=>["RedhatOne", "WinOne"]}
```

Comment: OH this is fantastic and exactly what i wanted - thank you!!
i really appreciate your help and i've learned loads from this issue.
I spent the last day or so trying to re-read about hash arrays as my fundamental understadning was also an issue. 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the shared values:

```
shared = hash1.keep_if { |k, v| hash2.key? k }
```

And them you could print that however you like. Don't know if you want to print the keys, values, or both, but however you like:

```
shared.each_pair { |k, v| print k, v }
```

You could obviously merge these two snippets into one command, but for the sake of clarity, they are 2.

**EDIT:**
Just noticed you wanted as an array. If you wanted just values:

```
array = hash1.keep_if { |k, v| hash2.key? k }.values
```

Thanks for the advice - i've tried this :

```
shared = Hash.new
grouped = hostArray.group_by{|row| [row[:server_host]]}
filtered = grouped.values.select { |a| a.size > 1 }.flatten
filtered.each do |element|
    element.each do |key, value|
   shared = element.keep_if { |k, v| element.key? k }
end
  shared.each_pair { |k, v| print k," ", v, "\n" }
```

end

but this output is still incorrect - i think i've referenced 'hash2' wrongly? is that correct?